# Yo men angularjs setup error

Tags: angularjs, ubuntu

I am using ubuntu 14.4 version . when i try to setup my project using yo men generator then i got such type error . please help me how i can solve it .

```
Running sanity checks on your system

✔ Global configuration file is valid
✔ Node.js version
✔ No .bowerrc file in home directory
✔ No .yo-rc.json file in home directory
✔ npm version
✖ NODE_PATH matches the npm root
npm global root value is not in your NODE_PATH

[Info]
  NODE_PATH = /usr/lib/nodejs:/usr/lib/node_modules:/usr/share/javascript
  npm root  = /usr/local/lib/node_modules

[Fix] Append the npm root value to your NODE_PATH variable
Add this line to your .bashrc
    export NODE_PATH=$NODE_PATH:/usr/local/lib/node_modules
  Or run this command
    echo "export NODE_PATH=$NODE_PATH:/usr/local/lib/node_modules" >> ~/.bashrc && source ~/.bashrc


Found potential issues on your machine :(
```

Comment: The fix is displayed at the bottom of the error message. Have you tried either of the suggestions listed under the `[Fix`] section?